# Which fires first? ASP SQLDataSource OR a C# Query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView where the user clicks on a delete button. When that delete button is pressed it's attached to an SQL datasource on the ASP page itself. Doing it this way alleviates having to select the row then delete.

I also have in the GridView an

```
OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
```

call. This method is rather simple in the code behind. The ASP SQL datasource checks a value in a table using a CASE WHEN and executes an update off of that or not.

I realized after that OnRowDeleting will always happen before the GridView control actually deletes it. It works correctly when the SQL data source doesn't fire execute. (I don't want it to based on that CASE WHEN clause) the OnRowDeleting method then fires and calls the Javascript call I have .. looks like this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {   
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "Ealert();", true);   
    }
```

The problem sits when the SQL datasource executes correctly as it's supposed to, the OnRowDeleting (GridView1_RowDeleting) still fires.

Is there a way to fire that Javascript only when the SQL datasource didn't execute?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I asked the correct question or not. However, doesn't matter. I found the answer I was looking for. Basically, I needed a way to access a certain cell in a row form GridView without selecting it. When pressing a delete button within GridView it calls its OnRowDeleting method I have setup. From there I select and compare its value like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell cell = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12];
        if(cell.Text == "Yes")
        {
            //Do Nothing
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "Ealert();", true);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }


    }
```

I didn't realize I could access the cell in this way. My original question might not make sense and doesn't seem applicable, but I asked it thinking I would have to run an SQL query on the code behind versus using the ASP SQL data source. Doing it this way solves everything in one.